# SQL two left joins and CASE statment

Tags: mysql, join, case

I have three tables like this:

**tags**

```
id  name  scope
----------------
6   abc   12
7   foo   12
8   bar   12
```

**builds**

```
id  name  scope_id
------------------
1   test1   12
2   test2   12
3   test3   12
```

**build_tags**

```
id  tags_id  build_id
---------------------
1   6        2
2   7        1
3   8        1
```

How do I construct an SQL query to show **for each tag**, and a **given build**, the **presence of** associated tags (build_tags)? So that the result is:

```
id  name  presence
------------------
6   abc   0
7   foo   1
8   bar   1
```

Right now I have this query which returns duplicate tags, as in two records for each tag instead of unique. I tried adding a `group by` but that resulted in incorrect `case` values.

```
select t.id, t.name,
    case t.id when tags_id then true else false end as 'presence'
from tags t left join
    builds b
    on t.scope = b.scope_id and t.scope = 12 inner join
    build_tags bt
    on bt.build_id = b.id and b.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have an incorrect case statement.

```
case t.id when tags_id then true else false end as 'presence'
```

try

```
(Case When t.id = tags_id Then "True" else "False" end) as 'presence'
```

Lemme know how that works I will try to help you more

Comment: that still gives me two rows for each tag. one row is presence=true, one presence=false for the two tags that have a record in the build_tags table

Comment: Oh hey can you try something like case when t.id= "your number" Then 1 end as presence. And you should end up with a Boolean value

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a group by trick:

```
select t.id, t.name, bbt.build_id, MAX(bbt.presence)
from tags t 
left join (
  select bt.tags_id, bt.build_id, 1 as presence
  from build_tags bt
) as bbt
on bbt.tag_id = t.id
group by t.id, bbt.build_id
```

You should have either 1 or NULL for presence for each build id / tag pair

Comment: so just to understand, we don't need the `builds` table?

Comment: well, the only information not available in build_tags or tags is the build name; unless you want the build name or need the scope as a join condition, there is no need for build table in this query

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went for something like this which uses `SUM` together with `GROUP BY`:

```
select t.id, t.name,
    sum(Case When t.id = tags_id Then true else false end) as 'presence'
from tags t left join
    builds b
    on t.scope = b.scope_id left join
    build_tags bt
    on bt.build_id = b.id
where t.scope = 12 and b.id = 3
group by t.id
```